# How to get latest value updated by another API called by API

Tags: asp.net-core, transactions

I have an issue related to transactions. I have 2 API applications. API from app A will call the API from app B. API in app B will update data in one table. After completing the call in API in app B, we will be get data using Linq again from the same table.

But the value does not change. Actually, when I add a breakpoint in the Linq code and check the database, the data has already been updated. Please help me solve this.

API 1 from app A:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var bookingInfo = await _unitOfWork.MasterBOFlightBookingRepository
                                       .Where(x => x.TravelmateId == "TF67271" && x.IsPrimaryPsgnr == true)
                                       .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    var originalName = bookingInfo.PassengerName; //it is will

    var client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7175/WeatherForecast");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }

    // re check value . Add break point here.
    bookingInfo = await _unitOfWork.MasterBOFlightBookingRepository
                                   .Where(x => x.TravelmateId == "TF67271" && x.IsPrimaryPsgnr == true)
                                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    var newName = bookingInfo.PassengerName;

    return Ok($"Change name from {originalName} to {newName}"); // it returns the same name Will
}
```

API 2 from app B:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "Get")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var personGenerator = new PersonNameGenerator();

    var bookingInfo = await unitOfWork.MasterBOFlightBookingRepository
                                      .Where(x => x.TravelmateId == "TF67271" && x.IsPrimaryPsgnr == true)
                                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    bookingInfo.PassengerName = personGenerator.GenerateRandomFirstAndLastName();

    await unitOfWork.SaveChangeAsync();

    return Ok(bookingInfo); //completed update data with random name
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem from api 1. Because of by default entity will be tracked by EF. So just add `.AsNoTracking()` to resolving the problem. Thank you !